# subsonic3 RESTHandlers

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

at the Subsonic website, there is an example of how to create RESTHandlers for Subsonic (http://subsonicproject.com/docs/JSON_Handler). I cannot find the referenced namespaces and classes in Subsonic3. Have they been removed ? And if not, how do I create the RESTHandlers in Subsonic3?

thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is only relevant to SubSonic 2.2 and wasn't included in 3.0

Comment: It would be pretty easy to take the code from the SubSonic.WebUtility namespace in 2.2 and use it - it uses very little of SubSonic, and could be adapted to work with SubSonic 3.0.  However, using such a thing on any site in production is pretty much a terrible idea.